# Soft keyboard without an EditText & detecting key presses

Tags: android, keyboard, onkeydown

How can I detect key presses reliably with a hard or soft keyboard?

My app remotely controls another device over wifi, and I need to detect every key press on either a soft or hard keyboard.  I don't really need an EditText because I just need to send the characters one at a time as they are pressed and don't need the final text string.

I have tried using an EditText with OnKeyPress, but ran into the problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967740/onkeylistener-not-working-with-soft-keyboard-android) with not getting key presses with soft keyboards.  And [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) isn't a good option because I need each key press.

I'll use an EditText if I have to, but would prefer not to.  What I really want is to:

- Bring up a soft keyboard when the user hits a Search button
- User presses keys and I transmit the codes to remote device.  Don't really need to see anything on screen in an EditText since it will be shown on the remote device
- User presses the custom Done button on the soft keyboard to close it

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you found a way to do this yet?

Comment: Take a look at [this][1] post. This works for me. Tested on SGS II.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579544/can-i-use-the-soft-keyboard-without-an-edittext/6954401#6954401

Answer (score 1):

Well you could override the [`onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`][1] and(or) [`onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`][2]
 methods in the applications activity class, this would allow you to get notification even about such keys as the back key and other hardware keys...

Note: you can get notification about trackball movement and so on...

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown(int, android.view.KeyEvent)
  [2]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyUp(int, android.view.KeyEvent)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work with a soft keyboard. I'm overriding onKeyDown and it isn't triggered with letters or numbers.