# Update TextView with each key press

Tags: java, android, view, switch-statement

What I am trying to do is update a TextView with each key event - basically copying the contents of the EditText to the TextView. For some reason, it's not working. Here's the code:

```
    View.OnKeyListener keyHandler = new OnKeyListener(){

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            TextView id = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.previewEmplIdData);
            TextView fn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.previewNameData);
            TextView ttl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.previewTitleData);
            TextView mgr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.previewMgrData);
            TextView loc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.previewLocData);
            TextView strt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.previewStartData);
            String text = "";
            EditText et;
            switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.etFirstName:
                et = (EditText)v; // must first switch to a text field
                text = et.getText().toString();
                fn.setText(text);
                break;
            case R.id.etLastName:
                et = (EditText)v;
                text = et.getText().toString();
                break;
            case R.id.etEmplId:
                et = (EditText)v;
                text = et.getText().toString();
                id.setText(text);
                break;
            case R.id.etStartDate:
                et = (EditText)v;
                text = et.getText().toString();
                strt.setText(text);
                break;
            case R.id.etTitle:
                et = (EditText)v;
                text = et.getText().toString();
                ttl.setText(text);
                break;
            case R.id.spinnerLocation:
                break;
            case R.id.spinnerManager:
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Basically I'm switching through the View id's on key press, and then casting the view to the EditText. I'm not really sure why this doesn't work...I've always been pretty unlucky with getting switch statements to work. Any help please?

Comment: which TextView does not shows the text?

Comment: None of them show anything..nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you apply this `keyHandler`? If you just created and initialized it, but didn't used in any view, it won't run at all.

Comment: Oh...that's probably what it is. How would I apply it to the current view? `getContext().setOnKeyListener()`?

Comment: If you want to apply it to the activity content view, it's better to change `setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout)` in the activity `onCreate` to something like `View activityView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_layout); setContentView(activityView)` and after the creation of `keyHandler` use `activityView.setOnKeyListener(keyHandler);`. But the idea of @woodshy is actually better :)

Comment: As far as I remember, you can use `onKeyDown` event of the activity to intercept virtual keyboard. But you'll have to operate with keycodes, not strings.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still having issues with it working correctly. I think I will check out woodshy's solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OnKeyListener does not work with soft keyboard. You should implement [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to track text changes. Also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967740/onkeylistener-not-working-with-soft-keyboard-android).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this. I got it working and it force closed when I used the soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this same issue using the following:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InputField extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText input;
private TextView displayString;
private String writeText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input_field);

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    displayString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayStringText);

    input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            writeText = input.getText().toString();
            displayString.setText(writeText);
        }
    });

  }
}
```