# Disable/detect keyboard dissmiss key in android softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Some softkeyboards in android come with a keypad dismiss key. is there a listener associated with this key ? editor action listeners or onKeyPreIme or dispatchKeyEvent did not work. Or is there a way to disable this key ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things working against you.

It seems that the hide keyboard key is somewhat special in that only the IME that has it can listen for it. Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/t4M8Zb9IomY

Also it seems that getting Keyevents for the soft keyboard within your activity is spotty at best: 
[onKeyListener not working with soft keyboard (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967740/onkeylistener-not-working-with-soft-keyboard-android)

I've just tested out `onKey()`, `dispatchKeyEvent()`, and `dispatchKeyEventPreIme()` on an EditText on the HTC Evo 4g LTE. None of the above receive callbacks for any keys on the soft keyboard except for backspace and enter. Everything else including the hide keyboard key skipped over my overridden methods completely.

I conclude that there is no way to get it working how you want.