# Error to updating EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

On some devices, with this code, the EditText to_quantity is not updated in real time during the insertion of the value to be converted in the EditText from_quantity. What can be the problem?

EDIT TEXT from_quantity:

```
from_quantity.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

        try{
        if(!(Double.isNaN(Double.valueOf(from_quantity.getText().toString())))){
                                                  convert(from_quantity.getText().toString(), "to");
        }
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            Log.d("error", e.toString());
        }
            return false;
        }
        });

            from_quantity.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                    //Clear Quantities
                                    from_quantity.setText("");
                                    to_quantity.setText("");
                                    return false;
                            }

            });
```

EDIT TEXT to_quantity:

```
to_quantity.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
     public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         try{
            if(!(Double.isNaN(Double.valueOf(to_quantity.getText().toString())))) {
                  convert(to_quantity.getText().toString(), "from");
            }
          } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
               Log.d("error", e.toString());
          }
          return false;
     }
});


to_quantity.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          //Clear Quantities
          from_quantity.setText("");
          to_quantity.setText("");
          return false;
      }

});
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve bro? you can use on focus change listener on edit text and do stuffs there realtime when edittext gain or lose focus.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the soft keyboard of your device, the OnKeyListener will not be called. You should use a TextWatcher.

[onKeyListener not working with soft keyboard (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967740/onkeylistener-not-working-with-soft-keyboard-android)

Answer (score 0):

Some software keyboards do not launch onKey() events. Create a `TextWatcher` and set it as a listener to the `EditText` instead:

```
to_quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        String text = s.toString() ;
        try{
            if(!(Double.isNaN(Double.valueOf(text)))) {
                convert(text, "from");
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            Log.d("error", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: but in this way the two EditText, from_quantity and to_quantity, are not coordinated ie the added is distorted

Comment: I don't understand what it means not coordinated... Use a `TextWatcher` in both `EditText` fields, it's the same as what you were trying to do except that I used a `TextWatcher` instead of `OnKeyListener`. If the code inside it doesn't do what it was supposed to do, that's a different matter.

Comment: practically, in from_quantity I enter the number to convertitre and at the same time it is converted to to_quantity. But using the TextWatcher, the cursor is not simultaneous with edidtext to_quantity

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna use soft keyboard you need to setFocusable to target view:

```
setFocusableInTouchMode(true); //Enable soft keyboard on touch for target view

setFocusable(true); //Enable hard keyboard to target view
```